# How can I set an attribute on individual select fields in date?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to set an attribute for the select fields in my date field via twig. Ideally I would have a piece of code that would look like:

```
{% setAttribute(myForm.myDate.day, {'attr': {'p-class': myForm.myDate.vars.id }}) %}
{% setAttribute(myForm.myDate.month, {'attr': {'p-class': myForm.myDate.vars.id }}) %}
{% setAttribute(myForm.myDate.year, {'attr': {'p-class': myForm.myDate.vars.id }}) %}
{{ form_row(myForm.myDate) }}
```

How can I do this in twig/symfony2?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to just output each field individually:

```
{{ form_widget(myForm.myDate.day, {'attr': {'p-class': myForm.myDate.vars.id }}) }}
{{ form_widget(myForm.myDate.month, {'attr': {'p-class': myForm.myDate.vars.id }}) }}
{{ form_widget(myForm.myDate.year, {'attr': {'p-class': myForm.myDate.vars.id }}) }}
```

Another way is [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: I can't do that. There's alot of styling I don't want to do because we've styled the form using {{ form_row() }}. There is much too much to change if we do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options:

**Put the ID onto the parent div tag using TWIG**

This would mean you need to tweak what ever JS / CSS you're using.

```
{{ form_row(myForm.myDate, { 'attr': {'class': myForm.myDate.vars.id} } )
```

**Use CSS pseduo selectors:**

It's unlikely you're wanting just to style the output (you're populating the ID) but you can always use CSS selectors for styling

```
<div class="some-selector">
    <select><option>YEAR</option></select>
    <select><option>MONTH</option></select>
    <select><option>DAY</option></select>
</div>

.some-selector select { color: green; }
.some-selector select + select { color: red; }
.some-selector select + second + select { color: blue; }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FFpJ8/

**Form theming**

As Elnur says you can also use form theming: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html
The default themes can be seen at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

You could therefore override the date_widget in your own theme adding in the id as necessary.

```
{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
                '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month),
                '{{ day }}':   form_widget(form.day),
            })|raw }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}
```

**JS**

You can supply the class using JS after page load, but I wouldn't.